# How do I build a system to view a user's profile contents trough a link

Tags: python, django

I already have a profile viewing and updating page for user. But I want everyone able to view the users profile through a link in the user's post.

views.py:

```
def teacherprofile(request, id):
    userT = User.objects.filter(id=id)
    return render(request, 'viewprofile.html', {'posts': userT})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('home', views.index, name='home'),
    path('signup', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('postskill', views.postskill, name='postskill'),
    path('profile', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('teacherprofile/<int:id>',views.teacherprofile, name='teacherprofile'),
    path('post/<int:id>', views.post, name='post'),
    path('post_delete/<int:pk>', views.post_delete, name='post_delete')
]
```

home.html template from where the url for teacherprofile is called:

```
{% for a in skills %}
          <ul>
          <div class = "rca">
            <li>Posted By: <a href="{% url 'teacherprofile' a.id %}"> <h5> {{a.teacher_name}} </h5></a></li>
            <li>Subject Type: {{a.skill_type}}</li>
            <li>Subject Name: {{a.name}}</li>
            <li>Duration: {{a.duration}} months</li>
            <li>Cost: Rs. {{a.cost}}</li>
            <li>Location: {{a.location}}</li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

viewprofile.html template:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}


<img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{posts.image.url}}" height="100" width="100">
<h5> First Name: {{posts.first_name}} </h5>
<h5> Last Name: {{posts.last_name}} </h5>
<h5> Username: {{posts.username}} </h5>
<h5> Email: {{posts.email}} </h5>
<p> Bio: {{posts.profile.bio}} </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Note: there is no error log. when i click on someone's profile . the fields are blank.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY1B1.png)

Comment: share error log

Comment: there is no error log. when i click on someone's profile . the fields are blank.https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY1B1.png

Answer (score 0):

in your `views.py` add .first() in your userT:

```
def teacherprofile(request, id):
    userT = User.objects.filter(id=id).first()
    .....
```

the filter is return `QuerySet[]`. the `get_object_or_404` is return Instance, so you have to use `.first()` to get the user in `QuerySet[]`, or use `get_object_or_404.`